# Why is openpyxl now requiring absolute paths to load files?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Loaded an old project that uses openpyxl to open an xlsx and experienced *badzipfile: file is not a zip file*.

Had to change

```
filename = 'output.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename)
```

To

```
path = "C:/Users/BigGuy/Documents/VSCode/Project/"
filepath = open(os.path.join(path, 'output.xlsx'), 'r')
wb = load_workbook(filepath.name)
```

File is still located in local directory and wasn't corrupted, also was able to import a file from same directory using local path with `open(filename)`.

Are other people able to open an xlsx file using local pathing? This worked a week ago without issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, most probably, old script was working static working directory, and your current one is not same path for project, please check your working directory.

```
os.getcwd() # from os module
```

if it is different from "C:/Users/BigGuy/Documents/VSCode/Project/", if it is, change working directory, then it will work as before

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/BigGuy/Documents/VSCode/Project/')
```